# Authentication not working in subdirectories of Wordpress blog installed in IIS8.5

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress, iis

I have a Wordpress blog installed in a IIS 8.5 machine and I'm using forms authentication using the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/login/login.aspx" name="authcookies" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

I also have:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

to prevent unauthenticated users from accessing the blog.

When I try to access `www.test.com/blog` when I'm unauthenticated it redirects me to the login page but if I go to `www.test.com/blog/subdir` it ignores the authentication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a handler to force IIS to run requests for php pages through the .net authorisation pipeline. Add this to the web.config inside the /blog directory:

```
  <handlers>                                                                                        
        <add name="phpauth" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
    </handlers>
```

Make sure the preCondition matches the bitness and runtime version of your app pool

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solved the problem. I created a new application pool running on 64bit, added that handlers config to the web.config and now it's working.